# SQL statement to select highest value for versioning purposes

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following records in table 'projects':

```
company_name version
COY1         1
COY1         2
COY2         1
```

I want to select only the highest version if the company name is the same like this:

```
company_name version
COY1         2
COY2         1
```

I tried this query but it seems to fail...

```
$sql = "SELECT company_name from projects P1 where version=(select max(version) FROM projects P2 WHERE P1.company_name=P2.company_name)";
```

What is wrong or correct way to do the select statement? Many Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I slap myself. I got a typo the statement works... I have corrected it. Admin please help to delete :(

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution. But it works

```
select company_name, 
       (
          select max(version) 
          from company where company_name = p1.company_name
       )

from (
       select company_name, 
              count(*)
       from company 
       group by company_name
     ) p1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25d32/2

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e51472/4

```
SELECT company_name,max(version)as`Version` from projects
group by company_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(version),company_name from projects group by company_name
```